# Sticky Nav JS only works if page loaded at top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a bit of code that adds the class `sticky` to my nav bar when you scroll down. However if the page is refreshed while scrolled lower down, or if I link to an anchor lower on the page, the class doesn't add till I scroll further down. It also doesn't add while scrolling up. How would I modify the code to add the class if the widow isn't scrolled to the absolute top?

```
var stickyTop = $('.primary-menu-container').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
        $('.primary-menu-container').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.primary-menu-container').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qccqzox/

Comment: I don't know jQuery very well, but could you use `$(window).load()` with the same function to solve the reload problem? For example, `function checkPageTop(){...} $(window).load(checkPageTop); $(window).on('scroll', checkPageTop);`

Comment: I found a bunch of solutions to do that but none seem to fix the problem

Comment: Could you please add the CSS code for the `.sticky` class? It might be possible to fix this problem with CSS alone.

Comment: Sure, here you are. https://jsfiddle.net/0qccqzox/